# Detect custom font size

Tags: theme-development, css

When a user changes the Custom Font Size of a block, it inserts CSS on that HTML element directly with a style attribute on render.

I expected there to be a class put on the element like `has-font-size` similar to `has-background` when a Custom Color Background is used.

Because of this there doesn't seem a way to detect a Custom Font Size.

Comment: I know why: It hasn't been implemented. But is that really your question?

Comment: Yes that’s what I’d like to know! Is there some freaking magical system that makes sure 72pt looks good on my screen? There would be an easy way to detect that, like custom colors. Idk seems like oversight.

Comment: Since this is a CSS question it's really better suited for StackOverflow. There are [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) in which you can target `[style*="font-size"]`. I imagine adding a style for font sizes and a class for font sizes would be quite cumbersome. You're more than welcome to add your feature request/suggestion on [Core Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/) but any answers here as to _why_ a specific choice in Core was made would likely just be speculation.

Comment: I understand, I think my question may be a bit too vague as to the purpose of my objective.

Comment: @NathanPowell this is worded almost like a rant, you may be able to claw back the upvotes by wording it differently, especially given the ambiguity. E.g. are you asking how to add the class? Or are you asking abut the decision process over on the gutenberg github? Describe the problem in more detail as well as what you are asking. Do not rely on comments too clarify the question, _edit it_

Comment: @TomJNowell Good point. I'll edit this to point out the specific issue and not be so frustrated.

Answer (score 1):

While you can not use CSS to detect Custom font sizes they can be disabled using this code:

`add_theme_support( 'disable-custom-font-sizes' );`

Then, to have more control over how the look of font sizes are, we can use:

```
    add_theme_support( 'editor-font-sizes', array(
        array(
            'name'  => 'Small',
            'slug'  => 'small',
            'size'  => '14px'
        ),
        array(
            'name'  => 'Normal',
            'slug'  => 'normal',
            'size'  => '18px'
        ),
        // etc.
    ) );
```

Then, where `size` is `small` here, we make a CSS rule like:

```
    .has-medium-font-size {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
```

Using the classes we can make logical breakpoints for the sizes.

Might help someone with a similar issue...